# Visual Studio 2019 blurry on certain files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I've got a strange problem, where only sql files on second monitor are blurry, the rest is crisp. I have the default settings [image: VS Settings]

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be caused by Windows scaling. I mitigated the issue by changing it to 100% on both monitors